# Indirect Lyapunov method for exponential stability

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

> Le the following non linear system:
> $$\begin{cases}
> \dot x_1=x_2\\
> \dot x_2=-x_1^3-x_2
> \end{cases}$$
> with $$V(x)=\frac{1}{4}x_1^3+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2$$

by Lyapunov Theorem I have proven that the origin is an asymptotically stable point. 
Since the jacobian of the function $f$ (let's rewrite the system in vectorial form as $\dot x=f(x)$) has an eigenvalue equal to $0$, I would say that surely the origin cannot be exponentially stable. Do you think it is right my intuition?

Comment: I believe you are referring to Hartman–Grobman theorem, which cannot deduce anything about the stability of the equilibrium point when it is not hyperbolic AFAIK. I didn't know for exponential stability $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda_i) < 0$ is necessary and couldn't find any source that claims so.

Comment: I am referring to the indirect lyapunov method for which we say thta: the theorem,  does not say anything about the case when Re[λi] ≤ 0 for all i, with Re[λi] = 0 for some i. In this case, linearization fails to determine the stability of the equilibrium point, although we can say for sure that if the equilibrium point turns out to be asymptotically stable, it will not be exponentially stable because the condition for exponential stability is both necessary and sufficient

Comment: I checked my copy of Khalil and see nothing is mentioned for exponential stability in Theorem 4.7 (Lyapunov's indirect method). And the discussions just before Example 4.14 are similar to your quote but doesn't mention exponential stability. I'm very interested about this statement, could you tell me the place of it in the book and the book edition? Mine is 3rd edition, 2002.

Comment: Ok I see it. Theorem 4.15 and Corollary 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

If we understand exponential stability as the existence of a lyapunow function $V(x)$ such that $V(x) = -\lambda \dot V(x)$ then from

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x_1=x_2\\
\dot x_2=-x_1^3-x_2
\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
x_1^3\dot x_1=x_1^3x_2\\
x_2\dot x_2=-x_1^3x_2-x_2^2
\end{cases}
$$
after addition

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 12x_1^4+ x_2^2\right)= -x_2^2\ge-\left(\frac 12x_1^4+ x_2^2\right)
$$

so

$$
V(x)\ge -\lambda \dot V(x)
$$

Comment: Your argument I think that does not work. Sctually I have just read this in Non Linear Control theory (Khalil): "The
theorem, however, does not say anything about the case when Re[λi] ≤ 0 for all i,
with Re[λi] = 0 for some i. In this case, linearization fails to determine the stability
of the equilibrium point, although we can say for sure that if the equilibrium point
turns out to be asymptotically stable, it will not be exponentially stable because
the condition for exponential stability is both necessary and sufficient."

Comment: Along the $x_2$ axis the stability is exponential but about the $x_1$ axis it is not.

Comment: I am talking about the stability of the origin! That for the reasones above so it is not exponentially stable

Comment: The origin is not exponentially stable of course!

Comment: Ok this is what I have required in my question!